# Negative number conversion to binary form in a byte(8 bits)

Tags: c#

I am trying to convert a negative number to binary form in 8 bits.
here is my code :-

```
 UTF8Encoding Bencoding = new UTF8Encoding();
 int a=-3;
 byte[] Bbuf = Bencoding.GetBytes(a.ToString());

 StringBuilder Binfobinary = new StringBuilder();
 foreach (byte b in Bbuf)
 {
     string str = Convert.ToString(b, 2);
     Binfobinary.Append(str);
 }
```

it gives me answer like this
101101110011

Comment: Are you actually converting characters/string (in UTF-8 encoding) or the number in two's complement form?

Comment: Actually I want -3 binary like this : 11111101

Comment: Are you looking for a BinaryWriter ?

Comment: @Kek : You should post it as an answer !

Comment: I have signed integer (-3) and want to convert this into binary form.

Comment: Do you want Convert.ToString(-3, 2)? It will convert -3 integer to string, representing its binary value.

Comment: It gives this "11111111111111111111111111111101" . I have already tried this.I want this answer like this "11111101" means in 8 bits

Comment: You know this limits you to +- 128 right?

Comment: @Ehsan Use sbyte instead of int.

Comment: No sir..Actualy I want binary in 1 byte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var str = Convert.ToString(-3, 2)
```

Comment: It gives this   "11111111111111111111111111111101"  . I have already tried this.I want this answer like this  "11111101"  means in 8 bits

Comment: @Ehsan And what is your expectations?

Answer (score 4):

If you want a 8-bit representation, your best bet is to strip off the extra 24 bits from the result of the 32-bit representation obtained by [`Convert.ToString(int, int)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14kwkz77.aspx) because there isn't an overload of `Convert.ToString(sbyte, int)`.

```
string str = Convert.ToString(-3, 2);
str = str.Substring(Math.Max(str.Length - 8, 0)).PadLeft(8, '0');
```

Of course if you want a 16-bit representation, you can simply cast the integer to a `short` to use the [`Convert.ToString(short, int)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1kwkfdz.aspx) overload:

```
string str = Convert.ToString((short)-3, 2).PadLeft(16, '0');
```

Comment: Note that this will fail *horrible* for all positive numbers. Why are you padding to the right hand side with zeroes?

Comment: @ØyvindKnobloch-Bråthen opps a horrible mistake, corrected. Thanks for reminding!

Comment: Oh shit...sir it fails for positive number.it gives wrong for positive 3.it gives "11000000"

Comment: @ Alvin Wong where is that

Comment: @ Alvin Wong this is right one.thanks for your help.